# Cut active part of the screen

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, resolution

Hi guys the problem is the following. I am using an application that shows daily event web metrics being displayed on a big screen. Because the application is web based and obviously quite limited there is no way to show the dashboards only, without  the browser or the navigation bars on the sides being visible.

What I was thinking of if there is an application that may allow me to zoom into that specific part of the screen (with the dashboards) so that everything else gets concealed.

I am looking for something that works similar to the Snipping tool but instead of making a snapshot just to zoom into the chosen area.

Thanks for the support :)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "active area" and "visible area"? Do you mean that you have a black frame around your screen?

Comment: Lets say I have the whole screen with some resolution, I want to cut a part of the screen to be only visible (e.g. the upper left corner), but rather without a black frame around but instead to expand the selected area to the whole screen.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), can you explain to us the bigger goal that you want to do this "partial blanking" for. It will help us give you better answers. (please edit your original question, not added as a comment)

Comment: You could always use the windows Magnifier and zoom in on a region of the screen. You will have terrible resolution, however what your asking to do entails that inherently.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Im with you. this is definitely an XY problem.

Comment: @Peyankov Why not just use the Windows zooming tool in accessibilities?

Comment: I think the OP wants something like what Microsoft Research did with [WinCuts](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/101729/WinCuts.pd).

Answer (score 0):

[ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx) from Microsoft Sysinternals team sounds exactly like what you are looking for.  Ive used it recently and it works fine.

> ZoomIt is a screen zoom and annotation tool for technical presentations that include application demonstrations. ZoomIt runs unobtrusively in the tray and activates with customizable hotkeys to zoom in on an area of the screen, move around while zoomed, and draw on the zoomed image. I wrote ZoomIt to fit my specific needs and use it in all my presentations.
>   ZoomIt works on all versions of Windows and you can use pen input for ZoomIt drawing on tablet PCs.